# Failed to spawn server object, Unity UNET

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I'm familiar with Unity and programming but I'm new to this site.

So I have an issue with clients on Unity. I start servers with no errors, flawless. But when I join a server as a client I get a bunch of the error mentioned in the title. What causes this issue? I am using the UNET networking components.

I think it's lines like these, when executed by a client:

```
    NetworkServer.Spawn (objectNameHere);
```

How can I fix it if that's the case?

Edit

After hours of having this issue I have become so frustrated that I think it's best I take a break. I'll check back on this site from time to time.

Comment: Just doesn't make sense. I wanted to play my game with my brother soon. It would be really nice if someone managed to see this before then.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you provide more details such as your code

Comment: An example of the errors wouldn't so amiss either. We need more details if we're going to help you out.

Comment: I found out it wasnt my code, but I didn't assign something in the editor :)

Comment: You should post back an answer so that when someone else is stuck you're helping them in the same way these people tried to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same trouble, and figured it out. In my Player prefab, under the Network Identity component I had not checked "Local Player Authority". Once I checked this all subsequently behaved as expected.